# Comment all lines matching some pattern

Tags: grep, pipe, sed

I need to comment out all lines containing "dlclose" for each file in the current directory and any sub-directories (recursively). This is my best guess so far given what I was able to find out from various guides.

```
grep -lIR "dlclose" . | grep -v ".svn" | sed -i 's/.*dlclose.*/\/\/&/g'
```

The two greps successfully find all files I want changed, but `sed` claims an `unterminated s command`.

Comment: Use a different delimiter with `sed` and you won't need to escape the slashes. That will make it easier to read. `sed 's|.*dlclose.*|//&|g'`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to edit in place (***`-i`*** option) the **`STDIN`**.

Remove *`-i`* option, it is useless.

*Note*:

You can speed up the command a lot **avoiding the second grep**, excluding at the root the unnecessary directories

Try

```
grep -lIR --exclude-dir=.svn "dlclose" . | xargs sed -i bak 's/.*dlclose.*/\/\/&/g'
```

or

```
for f in $(grep -lIR --exclude-dir=.svn "dlclose" .)
do
   sed -i bak 's/.*dlclose.*/\/\/&/g' $f
done
```